# /me/activities request Microsoft Graph Explorer successful 200 response but empty "value":[ ]

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the list of entries that can be seen in the Windows 10 timeline view via the User Activities API in Microsoft Graph.

I have selected the `UserActivity.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp` permission and am getting an `HTTP 200 Success` response, but the `value` returned is empty. I am signed in with a Work Account (O365)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/activities/recent?$top=5
```

When I look in the timeline view in Windows 10, I see a comprehensive history of activity. The machine is signed in using the same Work Account.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am also suffering from this too, any update?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/projectrome_get_recent_activities), only activities created by the current AppID will be returned:

> The `UserActivity.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp` permission will also apply extra filtering to the response, so that only activities created by your application are returned. This server-side filtering might result in empty pages if the user is particularly active and other applications have created more recent activities. To get your application's activities, use the `nextLink` property to paginate.

I'd suggest dropping the `$top` parameter and following the `nextLink` URIs to see if your app's activities show up deeper down the stack.

Comment: Marc, what about when there is no `nextLink` in the result set?  My calls to both *https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/activities/recent* and *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/activities/recent* are returning `{ "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(userActivity)",
    "value": [] }` with no `nextLink`.

Comment: If there is no `nextLink` then there are no additional pages of data.

Comment: Then I am confused as to what type of data the service should be returning.  What is an "activity?"  I am expecting to receive activities such as what sites I recently visited, files I may have uploaded or changed, etc.  Is this not what the API should be returning?

Comment: It only returns activities originating from your App ID. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/projectrome-activity?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: I think the app in this case would be SharePoint Online as I am calling the API via an SPFx web part (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial).  If SharePoint Online is the app with which the activity is associated, shouldn't it be returning things my user has done recently in SharePoint Online (i.e. browsing sites, uploading files, etc.)?

Comment: Unless SP is creating activities (which I don't believe it is), then no.